# How to insert a key value pair in an array of dictionary which is inside a dictionary in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, time-complexity

We have a JSON response which should be parsed before saving to Coredata, however we would like to parse it and do some modification before save.

```
[{
        "mailId": "316054287",
        "attachedDocumentCount": 3,
        "attachmentFileSize": 2932927,
        "confidential": false,
        "correspondenceType": "Transmittal",
        "mailNo": "AFDE-TRANSMIT-058698",
        "toStatusId": "3",
        "corrTypeId": "23",
        "reasonForIssue": "Client \"Proceed Subject ot Conditions, Revise and Resubmit\"",
        "referenceNumber": "Rebar-TRANSMIT-003389",
        "sentDate": "2022-04-21T15:02:42.637Z",
        "status": "N/A",
        "subject": "C2 - BCH Transmittal - Rebar Shop Drawings SW-EL-CH-07A & 07B - Rev 1 - Review Complete",
        "recipients": {
            "to": [
                {
                    "organizationId": "268497899",
                    "organizationName": "AFDE",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Tony",
                    "name": "Mr Tony Fournier",
                    "userId": "268832810",
                    "lastName": "Fournier",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Melanie",
                    "name": "Mrs Melanie Coffey",
                    "userId": "268841518",
                    "lastName": "Coffey",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268497899",
                    "organizationName": "AFDE",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Caroline",
                    "name": "Ms Caroline Rancourt",
                    "userId": "268842732",
                    "lastName": "Rancourt",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268497899",
                    "organizationName": "AFDE",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Mathieu",
                    "name": "Mr Mathieu Forcier",
                    "userId": "268844353",
                    "lastName": "Forcier",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268497899",
                    "organizationName": "AFDE",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Laurent",
                    "name": "Mr Laurent Gervais",
                    "userId": "268848608",
                    "lastName": "Gervais",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Ken",
                    "name": "Mr Ken Trinidad",
                    "userId": "268851135",
                    "lastName": "Trinidad",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Brian",
                    "name": " Brian Webster",
                    "userId": "268857121",
                    "lastName": "Webster",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Diana",
                    "name": " Diana Harrison",
                    "userId": "268863136",
                    "lastName": "Harrison",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Dan",
                    "name": " Dan Lavallee",
                    "userId": "268874809",
                    "lastName": "Lavallee",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268497899",
                    "organizationName": "AFDE",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Cole",
                    "name": "Mr Cole Daniels",
                    "userId": "268941632",
                    "lastName": "Daniels",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "James",
                    "name": " James Cross",
                    "userId": "268968788",
                    "lastName": "Cross",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "William",
                    "name": "Mr William Mint",
                    "userId": "268968789",
                    "lastName": "Mint",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Greg",
                    "name": "Mr Greg Smith",
                    "userId": "268968792",
                    "lastName": "Smith",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Andrew",
                    "name": "Mr Andrew Rayfield",
                    "userId": "268978580",
                    "lastName": "Rayfield",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Daniel",
                    "name": "Mr Daniel Sanderson",
                    "userId": "269015696",
                    "lastName": "Sanderson",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Vic",
                    "name": " Vic Levinsky",
                    "userId": "269017288",
                    "lastName": "Levinsky",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Greg",
                    "name": " Greg Tait",
                    "userId": "269029103",
                    "lastName": "Tait",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Brook",
                    "name": " Brook Alling",
                    "userId": "269033767",
                    "lastName": "Alling",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268497899",
                    "organizationName": "AFDE",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Julia",
                    "name": "Ms Julia Brin",
                    "userId": "269060417",
                    "lastName": "Brin",
                    "isRead": true
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Kevin",
                    "name": "Mr Kevin Demattos",
                    "userId": "269097068",
                    "lastName": "Demattos",
                    "isRead": false
                },
                {
                    "organizationId": "268446975",
                    "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                    "status": "N/A",
                    "statusId": "3",
                    "distributionType": "TO",
                    "firstName": "Shannon",
                    "name": "Ms Shannon Rochon",
                    "userId": "269125638",
                    "lastName": "Rochon",
                    "isRead": false
                }
            ],
            "cc": [],
            "bcc": []
        },
        "senderDetails": {
            "organizationId": "268497899",
            "organizationName": "AFDE",
            "firstName": "Neil",
            "name": "Mr Neil Cantwell",
            "userId": "269161169",
            "lastName": "Cantwell"
        },
        "mailBoxType": "inbox",
        "hasAttachments": true,
        "myMailsOnly": true,
        "isReadByMe": false
    }]
```

Here we would like to insert `mailId` from the top key value pair of each mail object and add it in each recipient object in `O(1)` or `O(n)` complexity like below,

```
{
                "mailId": "316054287",
                "organizationId": "268446975",
                "organizationName": "Harris Rebar",
                "status": "N/A",
                "statusId": "3",
                "distributionType": "TO",
                "firstName": "Shannon",
                "name": "Ms Shannon Rochon",
                "userId": "269125638",
                "lastName": "Rochon",
                "isRead": false
            }
```

The code we tried is going in `O(n2)` complixity. And its taking around 50 seconds to parse and save data. We want to reduce that.

```
    // json is saved in `mailResponse` variable
    public typealias JSON = [String: Any]
    guard let mails = mailResponse["mails"] as? [JSON] else {
        return nil
    }
    
    if #available(iOS 14.0, *) { 
        _ = mails.map { mail in
            if let recipients = mail["recipients"] as? JSON {
                
                var allRecipients: [JSON] = [JSON]()
                
                if let toRecipients = recipients["to"] as? [JSON] {
                    allRecipients.append(contentsOf: toRecipients)
                }
                if let ccRecipients = recipients["cc"] as? [JSON] {
                    allRecipients.append(contentsOf: ccRecipients)
                }
                if let bccRecipients = recipients["bcc"] as? [JSON] {
                    allRecipients.append(contentsOf: bccRecipients)
                }
                allRecipients = allRecipients.map({ recipient in
                    var mRecipient = recipient
                    mRecipient["mailId"] = mail["mailId"]
                    return mRecipient
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help on this is really appreciated.

Comment: Do you save there in the context? I don't see if you save or if it's hidden code, but if you save multiple times, you should save only one time.

Comment: Those are relationships, However the problem is in parsing and putting the mail id in each recipient object withe better complexity

Comment: Your latest edit is a bit confusing, you say that parsing and saving takes 50 seconds but the code that is now in the question is executed _after_ the parsing and _before_ saving so is it really the included code that is the issue?

Comment: I have removed the saving part as most of the code is out of scope. So our concern is parsing the response and manupulate the same.

Comment: But `mailResponse` contains the parsed json so that part is done. Have you considered using `Codable` with custom structures so you can get rid of all the casting?

Comment: I don't see any reason why `mails.map()` should take that much time. Could you check that's really taking that much time? Only that `map` at top level? Could you time the others? Also why `map` has a return value? Which one are you using exactly?

Comment: The first map is not creating issue, its happening in `allRecipients.map` as its going as O(n2) complexity

Comment: Make a type Recipient instead of using [String: Any] and test if that gives a better performance.